# Change comma separator to dot in table in Wave Analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics

I have a dashboard in Analytics app with Table. I need to display dot separator instead of comma as a thousands delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

in the left side panel you will see dataset fields, here select the measure which you were trying to change format and beside the name of the field. you will find a dropdown and you can format option over there

its basically ###### notation for example 
1. 100,000 you need to give ###,### as format 
2. 10,000 then ##,###
3. 99.99 then ##.## etc

if the column is calculated in compare table you will get the option of formatting just below the formula editor